# SSLError while installing Java using chef-solo

Tags: chef-infra

I am trying to install Java using Chef-solo but facing error below around certificates. I tried some of other solutions for downloading certificates and placing them at certain locations but that didn't work out. How do go about finding what's wrong?

```
sudo chef-solo -r https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/java.git
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:586:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0   state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:586:in `connect'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:553:in `do_start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:542:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:242:in `open_http'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:616:in `buffer_open'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:164:in `open_loop'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:162:in `catch'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:162:in `open_loop'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:132:in `open_uri'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:518:in `open'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/open-uri.rb:30:in `open'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.12.0/bin/../lib/chef/application/solo.rb:178:in `reconfigure'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.12.0/bin/../lib/chef/application/solo.rb:177:in `open'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.12.0/bin/../lib/chef/application/solo.rb:177:in `reconfigure'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.12.0/bin/../lib/chef/application.rb:68:in `run'
    from /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-10.12.0/bin/chef-solo:25
    from /usr/bin/chef-solo:19:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/chef-solo:19
```

Comment: What OS are you running? Have you tried updating the openssl package?

Comment: The "-r" option is used to download a cookbook tarball. You have supplied a link to a git repo. The SSL error you're getting is a different issue I'm also facing right now :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears to be a known issue in Chef. See:

- https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-4138